# why bootstrap has two container class?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have noticed bootstrap has two container class in there code one of them is the order of below: if you search in bootstrap (.container) you will find below code in Twenty-ninth of the search

```
 .container {
    min-width: 992px !important;
}
```

and the other class is:

```
.container {
width: 100%;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
```

why bootstrap has two container classes?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We need more context here, like which file(s) does this code appear in?

Comment: thank you , these two class are in bootstrap and l don't have any idea about there functions together

Comment: They are the same `container` class. You can use the same selector in multiple places in a css file. That'll have the same result as having all their values combined in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First One for Normal view **and this one for print view [below]**

```
@media print {
.container {
    min-width: 992px !important;
  }
}
```